# Configure pgbouncer and postgresql in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, microservices, pgbouncer

How can I apply connection pooling with **pgbouncer** in my `docker-compose` file. I don't know if the `ConnectionString` of my containers are correct or not.

```
  postgredb:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  pgbouncer:
    image: edoburu/pgbouncer
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgredb
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_USER=dbuser
      - DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
      - ADMIN_USERS=postgres,admin     
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  commenting.api:
    environment:
      - ConnectionString=Server=pgbouncer;Port=5432;Database=commentDb;UId=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;Pooling=true;
    ports:
      - "5051:80"

  posting.api:
    environment:
      - ConnectionString=Server=pgbouncer;Port=5432;Database=postDb;UId=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;Pooling=true;
    ports:
      - "5052:80"
```

I get this error `Npgsql.PostgresException: '08P01: server login failed: wrong password type'`.

So far the closest configuration I found was in this repository [edoburu/docker-pgbouncer](https://github.com/edoburu/docker-pgbouncer/blob/master/examples/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml)

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if `pgbouncer` expects md5 authentication by default, but modern versions of postgres default to scram-sha-256. You can force postgres to use md5 auth by setting the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` and `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS` environment variables:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=md5
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--auth=md5
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  pgbouncer:
    image: edoburu/pgbouncer:latest
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_USER=dbuser
      - DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
      - ADMIN_USERS=postgres,admin
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

With this configuration, I am able to successfully connect to the database through pgbouncer.

Comment: And should I change `connectionstrings` in the containers(in the question)?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary; nothing in the connection string is impacted by this configuration.

Comment: But when I use this `ConnectionString=Server=pgbouncer;Port=5432;Database=postDb;UId=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;Pooling=true;` I get error `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing that error. I don't know what software you're using that interprets that connection string. Your question was specifically about getting pgbouncer to talk to postgres, and using the configuration in this answer you can verify (e.g. using the `psql` command) that it works as expected. If you're able to successfully test the connection using `psql` but you're getting errors with your software, that might be worth opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Iarsks explained, new versions of postgresql (from 14) use scram-sha-256 by default. Good article about that [here](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/pgbouncer-scram-authentication-postgresql)

It is possible to use pgbouncer with `AUTH_TYPE=scram-sha-256` but by using
`image: rmccaffrey/pgbouncer:latest` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rmccaffrey/pgbouncer/), as stated in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/edoburu/docker-pgbouncer/issues/68)

Also in production with kubernetes for example, make sure to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` as the database host.

I created a [github repository](https://github.com/GuillaumeCisco/testpgbouncer) for showing how to configure things, md5 and scram with last postgresql versions.